# Add new sheet in Excel from windows application c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, windows

Hi i want to add new sheet and populate data from data-table into excel from windows application c#.If If the excel is already existing i have to create a new sheet for the same excel and get data from db using datatable and save. while adding new sheet i get typemismatch error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEI6O.jpg
Please help. Code attached.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblBrand", con);
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_data");
                    ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    string folder = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName + "\\OutPut\\";
                    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                        if(System.IO.File.Exists(folder + "sample.xlsx"))
                        {
                            Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
                            app.DefaultSaveFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook;
                            Excel.Workbook xwb = app.Workbooks.Open(folder + "sample.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
                            Excel.Sheets sheet = xwb.Worksheets;
                            var xlNewSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheet.Add(sheet[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                            xlNewSheet.Name = "newsheet";
                            // xlNewSheet.Cells[0, 0] = xwb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                            //xlNewSheet = xwb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                            xlNewSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xwb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                            xlNewSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xwb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                            xlNewSheet.Select();
                            xwb.Save();
                            xwb.Close();
                            releaseObject(xlNewSheet);
                            releaseObject(sheet);
                            releaseObject(xwb);
                            releaseObject(app);
                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Brands");
                            wb.SaveAs(folder + "sample.xlsx");
                        }

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ec)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
                }
```

Comment: Instead of using Excel interop which requires installing Excel on the server or client machine, use a library like EPPlus, ClosedXML or NPOI to create Excel files directly with far less code. Eg in EPPlus, you can create an Excel sheet from a DataTable with just `ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt)` or `ws.Cells.LoadFromCollection(list)` and eve `ws.Cells.LoadFromDataReader(dr)`

Comment: (which means that code you have there essentially comes down to a couple of lines)

Comment: If its a new excel i can create but if its an excisting excel i need to add a new sheet and then load data. Can u tel me how to do it ?

Comment: I used closed xml to create a new excel file. I am not able to add sheet to it . I get type mismatch error. Please help.